# Does git truncate files when pulling from a remote?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a web server running Apache and PHP. I want to know if Git interrupt access to files during a pull process.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it unless you're getting billions of monthly pageviews or you're deploying truly enormous files in this way.

Comment: AFAIK the git process runs in a separate thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git pull` is actually a shortcut for two commands:

This retrieves files from remote. You have a chance to interrupt it.

```
git fetch
```

This merges changes to your local branch.
Done in milliseconds

```
git merge
```

So, about the ability of truncating files:

1. As Thomas Kilian says, git process runs in it's separate thread. So it's not easily interrupted.
2. If you interrupt `git pull` (close the console, or your internet connection drops, or whatever), you actually interrupt `git fetch`. Since fetching is not completed, no truncated files will be merged to your branch. Repeat `git fetch` or `git pull`, let it finish, and you've got the valid copies of your files.
3. If by some chance Git managed to merge an invalid state (say, power went off during merging), you always have your previous commit. Do `git reset --hard <last-valid-commit-sha1>`.